# Using scp betweeen two machines with same PEM key

Tags: server, ssh, aws, scp

I'm trying to use scp to copy a directory between machines. I'm logged into the destination box 10.10.10.98 as ubuntu. (IPs are not real). I want to copy the theme directory `my-theme` from another box, 10.10.10.99. I can log into 10.10.10.99 as ubuntu OK in another terminal (OS X) window. Devops set me up with the same AWS PEM key for both boxes.

But when I run

> scp -r
>   ubuntu@10.10.10.99:/var/www/html/prod/wp-content/themes/my-theme
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme

it hangs, with no errors or progress. Do I need to specify the pem key? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try including -v option with scp? Also, -vvv might have extra helpful info.

This link might have something for you: https://superuser.com/questions/395356/scp-doesnt-work-but-ssh-does

Answer (score 0):

Re: Martin's answer, including `-v` option with `scp` was key to figure out the issue. I got the notice that

> debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.98 [10.10.10.98] port 22.

and it hung there. So obviously the one server couldn't connect to other, and the issue turned out to be a firewall and a VPN. So use `-v` when `scp` doesn't work.